# Google Scripting Assistance

Tags: google-apps-script

Im trying to setup a form that will email me peoples responses.

This is the current script:

```
function nl2br_(input_string){
  return input_string.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g,'<br />');
}

function contactUsMailer(e) {
  //  This script e-mails the contents of a form to a given recipient
  //  The form must have three fields in the order of: name; e-mail address; and message
  //  You must change the recipient variable below to your e-mail address
  try {
    var recipient = 'myemail@hotmail.com';
    var timestamp = e.values[0];
    var username = e.values[1];
    var option = e.values[2];
    var details = e.values[3];
    var body = username+' sent the following message: '+option ;
    var bodyHTML = '\
        <p>'+username+' <a href="mailto:'+username+'">'+option+'</a> below are the details </p>\
        <blockquote>'+nl2br_(details)+'</blockquote>\
        <p>Sent by the <a href="http://www.steegle.com/">Steegle.com</a> Contact Us Form Google Apps Script</p>';
    var advancedArgs = {htmlBody:bodyHTML , replyTo:username};
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, "Contact Us Form", body, advancedArgs);
  } catch(e){
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, "Error - Contact Us Form", e.message);
  }
}
```

This is how it looks when I get an email: 
[image: screenshot]

```
var timestamp - not important ignore it
var username - their username
var option - this is the "issue"
var details - detail of problem
```

I would really like it to look something like this:

```
Username: "username here"

Issue: "issue here"

Details:
        "wall of text for details here"
```

I've been at this for over an hour and a half and I can't get it to look anything remotely like what what is shown above :/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and this is how I solved it. 
I created a HTML Output with a table inside and then Sent this as My Email Body.

```
var log = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput()
 log.append('<body><table border="1">');
 log.append('<tr></td> Username:  </td><td>' + usernameVAR +'</td></tr>');
 log.append('<tr></td> ISSUE </td><td>' + issueVAR +'</td></tr>');
 log.append('<tr></td> DETAILS </td><td>' + detailsVAR +'</td></tr>');
 log.append('</table></body>'); 
var htmlContent = log.getContent();

MailApp.sendEmail(YOUR EMAIL GOES HERE ,"TITLE OF EMAIL", "SUBJECT LINE",{htmlBody:htmlContent} ) //Text as HTML
```

Good Luck!